# How do you persist a value you assigned to a model when posting it to a method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a `Model` that has fields.

I created an Editing page for it, so I return the view with this method.

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
        {
            Model model = new Model();
            model = retrieveModelFromContext(id);
            // Assign options to ViewData
            ViewData["Type"] = new SelectList(...);
            ...
            return View(model);
        }
```

So basically there are fields that I'd want to edit, but there are also fields that I would not like to edit. Then in my html I simply created a form:

```
        <form asp-action="Edit">
```

For the fields that I want to edit, I simply created inputs and assigned whatnot to them. For fields that I do not want to edit, I simply did nothing.

This action calls this `Edit` method:

```
       public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, Model model)
        {
            if (id != model.Id)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            // save model to DBContext
            ...

            return View(model);
        }
```

Problem is, for the fields that I did not display on the html view, their data becomes `null`. I tried to display and assign their fields but disabled editing, but that also just gives them `null` when they're disabled. Their values are only retained if I only display and assign them to the `View` and enable editing.

Is there anyway to work around this?

Comment: Instead of directly using your Domain Model using DTO's instead. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-5
And do the update using that DTO

Comment: @RigoSarmiento added an answer

Comment: Take a look at [JsonPatch](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2017/11/29/json-patch-asp-net-core/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a DTO (ModelEditDTO) and put the fields you want into place
and then mapping this DTO to Model 
and Editing This mapping can be done manually or with various tools such as automapper

For example :

```
public class Model
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }

}
 public class ModelEditDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Sorry I got busy. Thanks for this tip! I haven't tried it tho, currently working on different tasks. Will definitely come back in the future to confirm.

Comment: Hey I was bored at work and decided to take a look at my history and saw this. So yeah I'm currently in the future and I'm back to confirm this. Definitely what I needed was a DTO. Then use the Id from the DTO to retrieve the record when editing and save the new values.

Answer (score 1):

add this fields for things you do not want to be seen but values return null

```
Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Property);
```

or

```
<input type="hidden" asp-for="ModelProperty" />
```

this will make sure the values will not be null but not displayed in the view